# Any idea why these two boxes are offset?

Tags: html, css, height, width, overflow

In the fiddle below I have two inline-block DIVs that are the same size. They have overflow set to auto and have content in them. The second DIV has a rather large Y offset but I can't figure out why. They should just be right next to each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/nT4ku/

Any ideas?

Comment: which browser are you seeing this offset, on my FF 11 they are side by side perfectly

Comment: @Huangism Chrome. Latest version of stable channel.

Comment: k I see it now, the answer is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying a vertical-align on the side-by-side `inline-block` divs should fix this for you. `vertical-align: top;`

Here's my edit to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nT4ku/1/

Comment: It works in chrome, not sure about the rest.  Out of curiosity, what's the specific need for inline-block?

Comment: @ryanulit I'm rendering many fixed-size widgets to a page. Inline-block lets them line up side by side and drop down to the next line when the hit the edge of the viewport.

Comment: Gotcha.  Just watch out for the known issues.  The following link has a good explanation of inline-block display: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/